# Write a function that takes a function with specific parameters as parameter

Tags: scala

This title must be confusing, but basically I have a lot of functions that take one List[Double] as a parameter and return a Double. I want to make a function that only lets me take in functions that take a List[Double] and return Double.

I tried

```
private def testforNull(func(list: List[Double]): => Double)
```

but this gives me error. Can someone point me on the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured this out after reading a bunch of tuts on passing parameters and finally found one which had this:

```
private def testWithNull(func:List[Double] => Double) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use types to refer to this kind of function elsewhere

```
type ListToSingle = List[Double] => Double
private def testWithNull(func: ListToSingle) { ... }
```